# phpMyAdmin mysql database has huge traffic

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So im doing a project for which i have made an android application which communicates with a mysql database on phpMyAdmin. The android app sends requests to a php file which in turn communicates with the database. these php files are on the same server (000webhost) I have a bit of a problem though. Sometimes the connection doesnt work (eg. the data doesnt come through or i get a time-out error or something)

I have looked at the data traffic on phpMyAdmin and I think it is abnormally high (im not sure). The app is used by about 10 persons and the total queries should be about a 1000 a day. The queries are simple select and update actions. Though when I look at the data traffic (status) on phpMyadmin it says there has been 2.2 TiB data traffic total. Which I think is ridiculous. Also phpMyAdmin gives a lot of errors like "the rate of reading the first index entry is high" "and the rate of opening tables is high". And when I look at the monitor on phpMyAdmin it has random peaks of sudden 150 MiB data sent. Like, everything is incredibly high.

this is an example of a query I send to the database via php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("*************");

$ID = $_POST["ID"];
$naam = $_POST["NAME"];
$inbier = $_POST["INBIER"];
$outbier = $_POST["OUTBIER"];
$pof = $_POST["POF"];
$adjust = $_POST["ADJUST"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Bierlijst WHERE NAME = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $naam);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $ID, $naam, $inbier, $outbier, $pof, $adjust);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["NAME"] = $naam;
    $response["INBIER"] = $inbier;
    $response["OUTBIER"] = $outbier;
    $response["POF"] = $pof;
    $response["ADJUST"] = $adjust;

}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Is it possible that I'm running bad queries which are failing and looping and stuff?

Comment: Do you use any indexes? From your query you should have 1 on Name (because it's used in the WHERE clause). And maybe 1 index for each column you're extracting. I do the same thing (except for an iOS app) and indexes solved my performance issues.

Comment: No, I did not. I didn't think it was necessary because I only have 5 tables with about 15 entries each. It is a very small database.

Comment: Wow! Yes, you have other problems (if you are just using that SELECT with no complex JOINs).

Comment: Why would I use joins if my tables arent related